# How to convert .ttf to .fnt for use with M10_SCR.COM DOS font driver

Tags: ms-dos, font

I have a DOS program M10_SCR.COM that loads as a TSR and allows the use of fonts. It works with its own basic built-in fonts, so now I am trying to convert .ttf fonts into .fnt so I have more fonts to choose from.

There are instructions on how to convert .ttf to .fnt with FontForge at StackOverflow:
[How to convert TTF to FNT with Fontforge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529369/how-to-convert-ttf-to-fnt-with-fontforge)

I did successfully convert a .ttf font to .fnt, but it fails to load with M10_SCR. There are many options in FontForge that may be the cause of failure.

When running M10_SCR.COM with the converted font, it gives:

```
Error - wrong external font file size!
```

To troubleshoot, I tried loading one of M10_SCR's built-in fonts into FontForge. It gives these errors:

```
[dialog box: Bad magic number]
This does not appear to be a Windows FNT or FON file
[dialog box: Couldn't open font]
8x16FONT.FNT is not a known format (or uses features of that format fontforge does not support, or is so badly corrupted as to be unreadable)
```

I can't find any .fnt fonts on the Internet to try with M10_SCR for troubleshooting.

Why wouldn't a converted font work? How can I find out what the difference is? How can I get this to work?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what size is a .fnt file that the utility will accept?

Comment: since it emulates the video card's ROM character table, the characters must be the same size as those, therefore some multiple of 256 bytes.

there are three ROM tables: 8x8, 8x14, and 8x16 (character sizes). therefore acceptable filesizes are 2048, 3584 and 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 10):

This is Morozov’s screen driver, available *e.g.* from [SimtelNet archives](http://cd.textfiles.com/simtelctc/disk1/SCREEN/MXXDRV10.ZIP;1). It uses a fairly typical font format for EGA/VGA fonts, namely a dump of the in-memory font data as loaded for the character generator in an EGA or VGA graphics adapter: 256 characters each formed of 8 to 16 bytes (depending on the number of lines in the font), each byte encoding a line of a character — so the font files’ size is always a multiple of 256, 2048 bytes for small fonts (as used in 80×50 mode on VGA), 3584 bytes for 14-line EGA fonts, 4096 bytes for 16-line VGA fonts... This doesn’t match any of the `.FNT` formats available in other environments, such as Windows. I’m not sure whether there are any conversion tools available to produce appropriate fonts from TrueType fonts or other such formats; I don’t remember there being any in the 90s.

Fonts for tools such as this were usually hand-drawn using dedicated font editing tools such as [Michael J. Mefford’s `FONTEDIT`](http://cd.textfiles.com/garbo/PC/SCREEN/FONTED.ZIP) (originally [published in PC Magazine](http://cd.textfiles.com/swheaven1/UTILITY/BESTOFPC.ZIP), later released as shareware), or Oliver Fromme’s `CAFE` (my two personal favourites, which are unfortunately hard to get a hold of nowadays). You’ll find a number of fonts to try out, and font editing tools, in [SimtelNet’s “screen” directory](http://cd.textfiles.com/simtelctc/disk1/SCREEN/); look through [the index](http://cd.textfiles.com/simtelctc/disk1/SCREEN/00_INDEX.TXT;1) for details. I wrote a font-loading tool which supports a variety of formats, [`loadfont`](https://github.com/skitt/loadfont), although since it’s not a TSR it’s not as versatile as Morozov’s screen driver.

You can convert bitmap fonts in a variety of formats (including Windows `.FON` and `.FNT`) to raw fonts using [PSF Tools](http://www.seasip.info/Unix/PSF/), which are designed around [the PSF format](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/font-formats-1.html) commonly used for Linux console fonts. That provides access to a wide variety of font collections, and would solve your problem if TTF fonts can be rasterised to bitmap fonts.

Comment: that is what it is and where I got got it from. the Simtelnet "screen" directory has FNTCOL15.ZIP and I just tried it, they do work with M10_SCR however most are simply character sets for different languages, few are en-us.

Comment: next step would be to use those as examples of what format is required, then use something like FontForge to convert .ttf into *that* specific style of .fnt format,. suggestions?

Comment: one thing I notice is that these aren't .FNT they are .F08, .F14 and .F16 and looking again ye olde Win98 CD has .FON

Comment: one thing I notice is that these aren't .FNT they are .F08, .F14 and .F16 and are indeed 2048/3584/4096 bytes. looking again at ye olde Win98 CD it has .FON which don't work and are different filesizes too.

Comment: The file extensions don’t matter, they’re not significant. See my update for some more tools which should help.

Comment: Back in the day, I found it useful to employ extensions f08 for 8-dot fonts,f09 for 9-dot fonts, F12 for 12-dot fonts, etc. but I don't know if anyone else did likewise.

Comment: can confirm these are compatible with PSFTools RAW format. I've kinda got a workflow that does TTF to raw via otf2bdf → bdf2psf --fb … → psf2raw, but bdf2psf is fiddly and otf2bdf assumes all fonts are variable width. The results may be underwhelming. May be better going via [Fontforge and FNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529369/how-to-convert-ttf-to-fnt-with-fontforge) then fnt2psf → psf2raw

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that what you're dealing with here is two different file formats that happen to use the same filename extension, of ".fnt". There has never been any mechanism to control the use of filename extensions on DOS or Windows, except for market pressure, and .fnt is a very obvious choice for fonts.

- Windows [.fnt](https://file.org/extension/fnt) is pretty much obsolete, but it could contain vector or raster glyphs.
- Metagraphics [.fnt](https://www.metagraphics.com/metawindow/fonts/fnt-specs.htm) is a bitmap format that certainly isn't the same as the Windows format, and probably isn't the one used by M10_SCR, since it seems designed for fonts of higher resolution than MS-DOS INT10 usually deals with.
- M10_SCR [.fnt] seems to be something else.

I can't find much about M10_SCR on the net, but it's a minimum of 22 years old, quite possibly considerably older. Windows' use of particular filename extensions wasn't considered significant by many DOS programmers in the late eighties and early nineties, since Windows didn't have much market share until the advent of Windows 3.0 in 1990, and didn't become dominant in the PC market until the mid-nineties.

Comment: it's from March 1992

Comment: @Fyodor: Is the that the original release date, or the specific version you have?

Comment: the one I have. it says v 5.6 March 1992.

Comment: @Fyodor: The original release was presumably at least a couple of years before then, so we're back to 1990 or so. It would seem that Morozov either didn't know or didn't care that Windows used the same filename extension.